# Is there an option to pretty-print bit vectors as signed decimals?

Tags: z3

How can you pretty-print bit vectors as signed decimals in Z3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the command `(set-option :pp-bv-literals false)` to force Z3 to display the bit-vector literals in a decimal based format. Actually, it will display them using the SMT 2.0 format: `(_ bv<decimal> <size>)`. Consider the following example:

```
(simplify #x00f8)
(set-option :pp-bv-literals false)
(simplify #x00f8)
```

Z3 will print

```
#x00f8
(_ bv248 16)
```

Z3 has no support for signed decimals. We can add an option to display a bit-vector `n` as `(bvneg (_ bv<decimal> <size>)` if the most significant bit of `n` is 1. Is this enough for your purposes?

Comment: Thanks, Leo. It would be enough, but I only have these problems sporadically (when making exercises for students), so I'm not sure it's worth extra implementation effort just for that. I ended up encoding negation in the problem where I suspected the original satisfying value to be negative.